# Unable to boot Gigabyte P35K

Tags: linux, boot, bios, uefi

I use Arch Linux on my laptop. I use Gummiboot as the boot loader, but I use Legacy OS mode because when I try to boot in UEFI mode I get an unsigned image error (something along those lines, I forgot by now). I recently tried again. Same issue. When I went to the BIOS to switch back to Legacy OS mode, it would not let me. So I used "Reset to Win 8 defaults".

I rebooted, and the computer got stuck on the splash screen or whatever it is called. It had the Gigabyte logo, and the list of keys I could press to open the BIOS and Boot Menu. The fan started spinning up quite fast, and I could not access the boot menu or BIOS.

I have no idea how to fix this at all, and I would like to not have to take it in for repair or anything.

Comment: Go to BIOS/UEFI and turn off quiet mode/enable debug mode. There shall be some options for at least turning off logo so you can see, why it's stacking.

Comment: @frlan As I said, I cannot access the BIOS.